# Need help with the proof of Sylow's First Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Theorem: Let G be a finite group of order n and let p be a prime. Write $n=p^am$ with $a \in\mathbb{N}^*$ and $m \in\mathbb{N}$ such that p does not divide m.

(a) If P is a subgroup of G of order $p^b$ with $0 \leq b <a$ then there exists a subgroup $P^{*}$ of G of order $p^{b+1}$ such that P is a normal subgroup of $P^{*}$

(b) For every $b \in {0,.....,a}$ there exists a subgroup P of G with $|P|=p^b$

Proof (a) Assume that P is a subgroup of G of order $p^b$ with $1 \leq b<a$. Then p divides $[G:P]$ and, by Corollary 12.3, p also divides $[N_G(P):P]=|N_G(P)/P|$. By Cauchy's Theorem, the group $N_G(P)/P$ has a subgroup of order p. By the Correspondence Theorem this subgroup must be of the form $P^{*}/P$ with $P \leq P^{*} \leq N_G(P).$ This implies that P is a normal subgroup of $P^{*}$ and $|p^{*}|=|P|*|P^{*}/P|=p^b*p=p^{b+1}$

b) This follows immediately from part (a) by induction on b

Corollary 12.3: Let G be a finite group and let $P$ be a p-subgroup of G such that p divides $[G:P]$. Then p divides $[N_G(P):P]$

Ok, so in the first sentence. How do we infer p divides $[G:P]$. Can you explain in detail the theorems that were used to prove this and how they relate to the proof?.

I think now I understand the proof up to the correspondence theorem

Thank you

Comment: Serre's *Linear Representations of Finite Groups* gives a very nice proof.

Comment: The size of $G/P$ is just $n/p^b$ and it is given that $n=p^am$ and $b<a$.

Comment: For any subgroup  $S\leq G$. Each of the cosets of $S$ has the same number of elements as $S$ and together they form a partition of $G$. This means that $|G| = |G/S| |S|$ and hence $|G/S| = |G|/|S|$. By definition $ [G:S] = |G/S|$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $[G:P]=\frac{|G|}{|P|}=\frac{p^am}{p^b}=p^{(a-b)}m$. Since $a-b>0$, then $p|p^{(a-b)}|p^{(a-b)}m=[G:P].$ So $p|[G:P]$.

Consider the canonique projection $\pi:N_G(P)\longrightarrow\frac{N_G(P)}{P}$. Applying the correspondence theorem we see that every subgroup of $Im(\pi)=\frac{N_G(P)}{P}$ has the form $\frac{P^*}{P}$ where $P^*$ is a subgroup of $N_G(P)$.

Comment: Ok , now can you explain the correspondence theorem part?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I'll edit the answer.